# I need another phrase to replace "to be a part of helping the program grow."

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests

I have great passion and love for the Music Program and would love to continue to be a part of helping the program grow.

Answer (score 1):

People often refer to *contributing to the program*. This can be used whether they're actively involved in the program, or just providing financial support.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to say both "to continue being a part of the program" and "to continue helping it grow". Choose one or the other, as in "I have great passion and love for the music program and would love to to continue helping it grow."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

> I have great passion and love for the Music Program and would love to continue *facilitating its growth.*

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you may wish to help *fine tune* or *modulate* the program! Be a wit.